# Most pythonic way of ensuring a list of objects contains only unique items

Tags: python

I have a list of objects (Foo). A Foo object has several attributes. An instance of a Foo object is equivalent (equal) to another instance of a Foo object iff (if and only if) all the attributes are equal.

I have the following code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, myid):
        self.myid=myid

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            print 'DEBUG: self:',self.__dict__ 
            print 'DEBUG: other:',other.__dict__ 
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            print 'DEBUG: ATTEMPT TO COMPARE DIFFERENT CLASSES:',self.__class__,'compared to:', other.__class__
            return False    


import copy

f1 = Foo(1)
f2 = Foo(2)
f3 = Foo(3)
f4 = Foo(4)
f5 = copy.deepcopy(f3) # overkill here (I know), but needed for my real code

f_list = [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5]

# Surely, there must be a better way? (this dosen't work BTW!)
new_foo_list = list(set(f_list))
```

I often used this little (anti?) 'pattern' above (converting to set and back), when dealing with simple types (int, float, string - and surprisingly datetime.datetime types), but it has come a cropper with the more involved data type - like Foo above.

So, how could I change the list f1 above into a list of unique items - without having to loop through each item and doing a check on whether it already exists in some temporary cache etc etc?.

What is the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: This code CANNOT work: use `def __init__(self, myid):` instead of `__init(self, myid):`.

Comment: @glglgl: I spotted that too. I must have been correcting the code when you added your comment :)

Comment: Could you say more about what kind of attributes you're using? Are they all hashable themselves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I want to emphasize  that using `set` is certainly not an anti-pattern. `set`s eliminate duplicates in O(n) time, which is the best you can do, and way better than the naive O(n^2) solution of comparing every item to every other item. It's even better than sorting -- and indeed, it seems your data structure *might* not even have a natural order, in which case sorting doesn't make a lot of sense.

The problem with using a set in this case is that you have to define a custom `__hash__` method. Others have said this. But whether or not you can do so easily is an open question -- it depends on details about your actual class that you haven't told us. For example, if any attributes of a `Foo` object above are not hashable, then creating a custom hash function is going to be difficult, because you'll have to not only write a custom hash for `Foo` objects, you'll also have to write custom hashes for every other type of object!

So you need to tell us more about what kinds of attributes your class has if you want a conclusive answer. But I can offer some speculation.

*Assuming* that a hash function *could* be written for `Foo` objects, but also assuming that that `Foo` objects are mutable and so really *shouldn't* have a `__hash__` method, as Niklas B. points out, here is one workable approach. Create a function `freeze` that, given a mutable instance of `Foo`, returns an immutable collection of the data in `Foo`. So for example, say Foo has a `dict` and a `list` in it; `freeze` returns a `tuple` containing a `tuple` of `tuple`s (representing the `dict`) and another `tuple` (representing the `list`). The function `freeze` should have the following property:

```
freeze(a) == freeze(b)
```

If and only if

```
a == b
```

Now pass your list through the following code:

```
dupe_free = dict((freeze(x), x) for x in dupe_list).values()
```

Now you have a dupe free list in O(n) time. (Indeed, after adding this suggestion, I saw that [fraxel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536073/577088) suggested something similar; but I think using a custom function -- or even a method -- `(x.freeze(), x)` -- is the better way to go, rather than relying on `__dict__` as he does, which can be unreliable. The same goes for your custom `__eq__` method, IMO -- `__dict__` is not always a safe shortcut for various reasons I can't get into here.)

Another approach would be to use only immutable objects in the first place! For example, you could use [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s. Here's an example stolen from the python docs:

```
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(11, y=22)     # instantiate with positional or keyword arguments
>>> p[0] + p[1]             # indexable like the plain tuple (11, 22)
33
>>> x, y = p                # unpack like a regular tuple
>>> x, y
(11, 22)
>>> p.x + p.y               # fields also accessible by name
33
>>> p                       # readable __repr__ with a name=value style
Point(x=11, y=22)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a `set` (or `frozenset`)? It's explicitly for holding a unique set of items.

You'll need to create an appropriate `__hash__` method, though. `set` (and `frozenset`) use the `__hash__` method to hash objects; `__eq__` is only used on a collision, AFAIK. Accordingly, you'll want to use a hash like `hash(frozenset(self.__dict__.items()))`.

Comment: I'm confused. I **AM** using set() in my code snippet above. Could you point out where I'm going wrong?. I suspect its something to do with the `__hash__` method. An example (or pointer to one) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html), you need to define `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` for your custom class to work correctly with a `set` or `frozenset`, as both are implemented using hash tables in CPython.

If you implement `__hash__`, keep in mind that if `a == b`, then `hash(a)` must equal `hash(b)`. Rather than comparing the whole `__dict__`s, I suggest the following more straightforward implementation for your simple class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, myid):
        self.myid = myid

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and other.myid == self.myid

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.myid)
```

If your object contains mutable attributes, you simply shouldn't put it inside a set or use it as a dictionary key.

Comment: that doesn't work as the poster asked, he says two objects are equal if and only if all their attributes are equal. Your code only compares the myid attribute

Comment: @F.C: This is not a sensible approach in the first place. If an object has mutable attributes, it shouldn't be hashable. Other set implementations like search trees suffer from similar problems.

Comment: it depends on the object, I like to think the poster knows why he wants to do it that way. In any case, even if the object doesn't have mutable attributes your code doesn't comply with what he asked.

Comment: @F.C.: Well it answers the question why OP's original code wouldn't work with a set. When I wrote this answer, nobody else had mentioned that `__hash__()` needs to be overridden *at all*, so I thought it was worth mentioning. IMHO the question is not answerable in its current state. I think senderle has done a good job at pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method, just make a dictionary keyed by `__dict__.items()` for the instances:

```
f_list = [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5]
f_dict = dict([(tuple(i.__dict__.items()), i) for i in f_list])
print f_dict
print f_dict.values()
#output:
{(('myid', 1),): <__main__.Foo object at 0xb75e190c>, 
 (('myid', 2),): <__main__.Foo object at 0xb75e184c>, 
 (('myid', 3),): <__main__.Foo object at 0xb75e1f6c>, 
 (('myid', 4),): <__main__.Foo object at 0xb75e1cec>}
[<__main__.Foo object at 0xb75e190c>, 
 <__main__.Foo object at 0xb75e184c>, 
 <__main__.Foo object at 0xb75e1f6c>, 
 <__main__.Foo object at 0xb75e1cec>]
```

This way you just let the dictionary take care of the uniqueness based on attributes, and can easily retrieve the objects by getting the values.

Comment: +1 -- I just saw this after suggesting something similar. But I think doing this with `__dict__` is questionable; better to use a custom method or function that gets it right rather than a shortcut such as this. (I also think the OPs version of `__eq__` isn't great.

Answer (score -1):

If you are allowed you can use a set http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

```
list = [1,2,3,3,45,4,45,6]
print set(list)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 45])
x = set(list)
print x
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 45])
```